# Urban Airship API for automated testing?

Tags: testing, urbanairship.com

We have an existing set of applications that use Urban Airship for notifications.  We want to automate the testing of the server component.

We use automated testing as far as possible.  Specifically, I want to be able to validate that when I make a /api/post call for a specific tag, then Urban Airship generates a notification for that tag.

In an ideal world, I'd make a web REST call along the lines of 'return when notification received for tag=XXX or timeout', and validate that the response was what I expected.

Does such a call exist, or can anyone suggest another approach other than including phone hardware?

- Charles

Answer (score 0):

There's no end to end callback for any push service since it goes through a variety of other services (APNS, GCM).  In other words, you can't do an HTTP request to Urban Airship, then have a call back when the notification is received on the device.  The best that you could do, is use Urban Airship's API to do a post call to send the message, then check that the response is a 2XX response.  The 2XX response doesn't indicate that the push was received on the device, but it at least validates that UA has received the request to try and send that notification.

Another option that you could look into is using a service such as appthwack: https://appthwack.com/ I'm not sure if they are able to test push notifications, as it looks like they use emulators, but it's worth looking into imo.